# Why is my SSH session prompting for password for one host only?

Tags: ssh, password, key-authentication

I have an environment where all SSH connections go through a jump-box.  There are a bunch of linux servers, but to get to them I have to ssh to a bastien host then onwards.

One specific internal host keeps prompting for password

```
firewall ~ $ ssh m4
Password:
```

But connections to m4 from elswehere work with key auth fine.

`/var/log/secure` is unhelpful, with no errors.

```
 Jul 27 21:34:57 m4 sshd[29240]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
 Jul 27 21:34:57 m4 sshd[29236]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for root from firewall[192.168.9.248] port 4097 ssh2

 but from another host, pubkey works fine
 Jul 27 21:34:57 m4 sshd[29240]: Accepted publickey for root from m3[192.168.9.9] port 6090 ssh2
```

Why would SSH prompt for password for this one combination and not for others?

Answer (score 1):

I ran `ssh-add -L` to confirm my key was loaded

```
 firewall ~ $ ssh-add -L
 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAA.....snip.....VBQ== rsa-key-20170210
 etc...
```

Then I ran `ssh -v m4` to see what SSH thought was going on... and I had a lightbulb moment.

```
 firewall ~ $ ssh m4 -v
 OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
 debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
 debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for m4
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to m4 [192.168.9.74] port 22.
 debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
 debug1: Connection established.
 debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
 ...snip
 debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
 debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
 debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
 debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
 debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
 debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=20 dh_need=20
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
 debug1: Server host key: RSA 23:87:00:00:00:00:00:00:N0:N0:N0
 debug1: Host 'm4' is known and matches the RSA host key.
 debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1869
 debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive
 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
 debug1: No valid Key exchange context
 debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

 debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
 No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:0)

 debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
 Password:  ^C
```

That line `debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 11: Applying options for m4` caught my eye - there shouldn't have been anything specific for this host.

```
 Host 10.99.2.23       # m4 drac
    PasswordAuthentication=yes
    PubkeyAuthentication=no
```

So the physical host is a Dell server and has a dedicated OOB port for console access.  Dell calls this a DRAC port, and I have a DNS record set up for `m4-drac`

The DRAC is not configured to use SSH public keys for authentication, so this config stops it trying.  But the config was being applied to the hostname **m4** because it doesn't honour the hash.

**ANSWER** ssh's .config file does not observe the Hash as a comment delimiter.